# Memory usage with tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Is it expected behavior that with `tf.debugging.enable_check_numerics()`, CPU memory consumption can go up tremendously? I am talking here about a factor of above 2, in my case from 8 GB to 18 GB, just by enabling that, while running fitting on the GPU. My GPU memory consumption is unaffacted by that option.

It seems like that this doesn't occur for all networks, for me it is happening with an RNN with GRU cells and Dense layers. Frankly, I have gotten tired of finding the sources of memory leaks in TF 2.x, finding workarounds, and pinpointing the source of the problem by stripping it down to a minimum example. I have done the latter already for a memory leak, filed a bug ticket on git hub, got the memory leak confirmed, but no reaction after months. Memory usage in general seems to be a weakness of TF 2.x.

This time, it doesn't seem to be a memory leak, and now that I have found the source of the problem, I am happy with saving 10 GB of memory by not enabling that option. I am just wondering, if anyone has made similar experiences with that option and has some insights regarding interconnections.

EDIT:

- I am using 2.2.0-dev20200303.
- I just found out that in addition it
  leaks.

Comment: Can you point me to the GitHub issue so I can take a look again?

Comment: @ShanqingCai, thanks for asking. I haven't opened a GitHub issue for this memory leak. The above-mentioned memory leak with no reaction afters months is another one and the GitHub issue for that is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37479) one.